# lessphp import path issue, if I use manual import path

Tags: wordpress, import, path, lessphp

I am working on **lessphp** compiler for my own development needs, here is what I am trying to achieve.

a) I have parent theme and child theme both have less files.

b) Using **twitter bootstrap** less files

c) Parent theme have twitter bootstrap less files

d) I am trying to use less files from parent theme in my child theme less file by using @import

I have tried:
a) Passing paths as php variables by using lessphp setVariables(), and it gives me something like this.

i) @import "E:\wamp\personal\multisite/wp-content/themes/my-theme/bootstrap/variables.less";

ii) @import "E:\wamp\personal\multisite/wp-content/themes/my-theme/bootstrap/mixins.less";

code used:

```
@import "@{template_directory_path}/bootstrap/mixins.less"; 
@import "@{template_directory_path}/bootstrap/variables.less";
```

but its outputed as is in .css file instead of being imported as less file for parsing.

b) I tried to set directory search paths using lessphp addImportDir(), but it didn't worked either,

so anybody familiar with my situation, wanna help me out?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with encoding.  The less compiler I was using needs the .less files to be encoded as UTF-8 without BOM.  All of my files were encoded as UTF-8 with BOM.  Once I changed the encoding the files started compiling as needed.

Comment: Thanks. Though I have started using alternative approach but would love to have this one working.

Comment: This isn't explained anywhere.  I figured it out on my own.  You can use Notepad++ to convert the encoding of files to other encodings.  Make sure you set the less files to the proper encoding above and it will work for you.

Comment: This problem shows up particularly often with WAMP, in my experience.